# prove a sequence converges to $\sqrt[3]{3}$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $f: [1,\infty) \rightarrow R$ given by $f(x) = \dfrac{3x}{4} + \dfrac{3}{4x^2}$. Prove that given any $x \in[1, \infty)$, the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_1 = x, x_2 = f(x_1), x_3 = f(x_2)$ ... $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$.

Prove $x_n$ converges to $\sqrt[3]{3}$.

I find out the function has a Lipschitz constant $3/4$, but i have no idea how does Lipschitz continuous help with converges.

Comment: Do you know the Banach fixed point theorem (sometimes called contraction mapping theorem)?

Comment: @DanielFischer i do

Comment: Then all that remains is to check that $\sqrt[3]{3}$ is a fixed point of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking from where you left off, $|x_n-x_{n-1}|= |f(x_{n-1})-f(x_{n-2})|\le\dfrac{3}{4}|x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}|\le...\le\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{n-2}|x_2-x_1|\le \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{n-2}$. Thus if $m > n \implies |x_m-x_n|\le |x_m-x_{m-1}|+|x_{m-1}-x_{m-2}|+\cdots +|x_{n+1}-x_n|\le \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{m-2}+\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{m-3}+\cdots + \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{n-1}= \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{n-1}\left(1+\dfrac{3}{4}+\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^2+\cdots +\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{m-n-1}\right)= \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{n-1}\cdot \dfrac{1-\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{m-n}}{1-\dfrac{3}{4}}< 4\cdot \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{n-1}< \epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n \ge N_0$ which is easily chosen. This shows $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, hence converges to $a$ which equals to $f(a)$. So: $ a = f(a) = \dfrac{3a}{4} + \dfrac{3}{4a^2}\implies a^3 = 3\implies a = \sqrt[3]{3}$ as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $4x^2\cdot f(x)=3x^3+3$, and if $x$ is a fixed point of $f$ (i.e. $f(x)=x$) then $4x^3=3x^3+3$ and finally $x^3=3$. So the (only) fixed point of $f$ is actually $\sqrt[3]{3}$.

Can you show somehow that your sequence converges to a fixed point? As said in the comments, you probably want to apply Banach fixed point theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: thanks. I realize  Lipschitz continuous is actually contraction mapping